# Пучить и пучина — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Являются ли слова *пучить и пучина* однокоренными?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по материалам этимологических словарей, исторически  однокоренные.

Мнение Крылова:

> Пучи́на. Заимствование из старославянского, где образовано от puka —
>   «пучина», родственного к пукъ. К той же основе восходят выпуклый,
>   пучить.

То же самое у Фасмера и Шанского:

> **Пучи́на**. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Суф. производное от пука «пучина»,
>   варианта ж. р. к пукъ. Ср. выпуклый, **пучить**. Буквально — «то, что
>   вздымается».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0